# Backbone.js auto render view after destroy

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

I have the 2 views for my model.  One creates the ul view, the other add the li elements.  The views work but they do not update after the destroy function is called.  I've tried various ways to bind to the render function, but it is not being called after this.model.destroy(); What am I missing?

```
var NoteListView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName:'ul', 
    className: 'note-group',

    initialize:function () {

        _.bindAll(this, "render");    // I've tried all these:
        this.model.bind("change", this.render, this);
        this.model.bind("destroy", this.render, this);
        this.model.bind("reset", this.render, this);
        this.model.bind('change', _.bind(this.render, this));
        this.model.on('change',this.render,this);
    },
    render:function (eventName) {
        _.each(this.model.models, function (note) {
            $(this.el).append(new NoteListItemView({
                model:note
            }).render().el);
        }, this);
        return this;
    }

});

var NoteListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName:"li", 
    className: 'note-item',

    template:_.template($('#tpl-note-item').html()),
    initizlize:function(){
        this.model.on('change',this.render,this);
    },
    render:function (eventName) {
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },
    events: {
        "click .note-btn-delete": "deleteNote"
    },
    deleteNote: function(e){
        this.model.destroy();
    }
});
```

Edit: here's the Collection:

```
var NoteCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:Note,
    url:"api.php/notes",
    initialize: function (models){
        this.filtered = new Backbone.Collection(models);
    },
    filterByCid: function(id) {
        var filtered = _.filter(this.models, function (model) {
            if (id==0) return true;
            return model.get("contactid") == id;
        });
    }
});
```

In the router:

```
this.noteList = new NoteCollection();
            this.noteList.fetch({data:{contactid:id},
                success: function (collection){
                    if (collection.length>0){
                            $('#note-container').html(new NoteListView({model:collection}).render().el);
                        }
                        else {
                            $('#note-container').html('No notes');
                        }
                }
            })
```

Comment: Isn't this `this.model.models` supposed to be `this.collection.models`

Answer (score 2):

I see 2 issues with your code.

**First**

You are not listening to the `remove` event on  the **NodeListItemView**

**Second**

```
 _.each(this.model.models,
```

supposed to be

```
 _.each(this.collection.models,
```

If **models is present on the model,** then it is supposed to be in the options of the model

```
 _.each(this.model.options.models,
```

**Code**

```
var NoteListView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: 'ul',
    className: 'note-group',
    initialize: function () {
         this.listenTo.on(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
    },
    render: function (eventName) {
        _.each(this.collection.models, function (note) {
            $(this.el).append(new NoteListItemView({
                model: note
            }).render().el);
        }, this);
        return this;
    }

});

var NoteListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "li",
    className: 'note-item',

    template: _.template($('#tpl-note-item').html()),
    initizlize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, "deleteNote", "removeView");
        this.listenTo.on(this.model, 'change', this.render);
        this.listenTo.on(this.model, 'remove', this.removeView);
    },
    render: function (eventName) {
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },
    events: {
        "click .note-btn-delete": "deleteNote"
    },
    deleteNote: function (e) {
        this.model.destroy();
    },
    removeView : function() {
        this.remove();
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

Change this line

```
new NoteListView({model:collection}).render().el
```

to use collection instead

```
new NoteListView({collection :collection}).render().el
```

And I do not believe your `fetch` method takes in any data

```
    this.noteList.fetch({data:{contactid:id})

    this.noteList.fetch()
```

It only takes in success and error callbacks

Comment: Is it "this.listenTo(...) not this.listenTo.on(...)?  Also, I should have mentioned that I'm using a filter function on the Collection, which is why I'm using _.each(this.model.models, function (note) {...}.  See additional code above.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, the filter is actually not the issue and is not used.  It seems my issue is in the router.  Please see the code from the router above.

Comment: @mozgras .. Glad to have helped :)